# python request a website with post method

Tags: python, post

Hey i'm trying to request a website with parameters using post method, Here are the following Form Data of the website

```
First: name
Last: lastname
Email: email@gmail.com
CountryID: 53
City: Misgav Regional Council
Postcode: 4848484
petition_id: 613908
action: sign
Is_shared_on_fb: 0
cid: 1508
skin: community_petitions
lang: he
supports_history_api: true
secure_validation: Thu Dec 06 2018 21:45:24 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)
used_js: Thu Dec 06 2018 21:45:24 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time)
postaction_data: eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo5OTg0NTUwNSwic3RvcmFnZSI6eyJwb3N0YWN0aW9uX3BhZ2UiOiJwb3N0YWN0aW9uLXVzZXItcGV0aXRpb24iLCJwZXRpdGlvbklEIjoiNjEzOTA4In19
cookie_id:
```

The problem is I am not sure what data does requests() needs. I've tried the following with no success, thank you for your help!

```
import requests

p  = requests.post('https://secure.avaaz.org/he/community_petitions/brykh_bbyt_spr_hmnhlt_shl_byt_spr/?asljNcb', data={'First': 'name', 'Last': 'lastname', 'Email': 'email@gmail.com' , 'CountryID': '53', 'City': 'Misgav Regional Council' , 'PostCode': '4848484', 'petition_id': '613908', 'action': 'sign'})
print(p.text)
```

Comment: what do you get back?  what are you expecting back?

Comment: @SamMason i don't really know what i get back, that's the problem, i know i'm getting the html page but i cant rlly view it, i think i'm getting an error. i'm excepting the program to sign to the petition, and when it does it, i can view who signed for it so i can know if the program worked.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the docs on the `requests` package…  it has lots of examples of ways checking http status codes and getting content out from the response